# JUnit 5 Jupiter tags using extension

Tags: junit5, junit5-extension-model

All my DB tests are annotated with a custom `DbExtension` extension. I want to also tag these tests so I can run them separately in the CI.
Is there anything I can add on the extension class so that it will tag all extending tests?

just to illustrate (in kotlin):

```java
    class DatabaseExtension : ParameterResolver, AfterEachCallback {
       //setup connection
    }

    @ExtendWith(DatabaseExtension::class)
    @Tag("db) //Can we have this tag in the extension class instead of each test
    class MyDbTest {

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not at/by the extension, but that would be a neat feature. Do you mind opening a feature request at https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/new/choose ?

You may create your own composed annotation, though. Something like the following:

```java
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Tag;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;

@ExtendWith(DatabaseExtension.class)
@Tag("db")
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Databased {}
```

Usage:

```java
@Databased
class MyDbTest {}
```

See https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-meta-annotations for more details.

Comment: I like your suggestion, I guess it's more flexible and composable than statically setting the tag in the extension